# how to separate coordinates to groups of nearby coordinates

Tags: coordinates

I have coordinates (lattitude and longitude) of some cities and I want to create groups of nearby cities. You can see illustration:

[image: Grouped coordinates]

Do you know some tips, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. narrow down on closely cities. I.e. Lat < pos_lat + d && lat > pos_lat - d && lon < pos_lon + d && pos_lon > pos -d
2. Narrow down on closest to farthest by calc distance where
   d = sqrt( (pos_lat - lat)^2 + (pos_lon - lon)^2)

Answer (score 2):

There is an example script at the bottom of this page to find the distance between the coordinates.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

If you worked out the distance for each pair of cities you could then use something like k-means clustering to create groups.